# Why is windowDidLoad() is called twice in a segue?

Tags: swift, segue, appkit, nswindowcontroller, nsstoryboard

I have a storyboard-based `AppKit` app written in `Swift`. The issue is that two of my storyboard-based `NSWindowController` which are trigged by segue from the main `NSWindowController`, the `windowDidLoad()` method is called twice. I can't work out why and how.

```
class AnotherWindowController: NSWindowController {
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        // ...
        print("Is this called once?")
    }
}

// Prints:
//  Is this called once?
//  Is this called once?
```

Whereas the main `NSWindowController`, the `windowDidLoad()` method is called only once. I also tried opening another main `NSWindowController` and the result is the same as launching the app the first time.

Why is this a problem for me? I want to do some view setup in `windowDidLoad()` method in `AnotherWindowController`. Its `contentViewController` is a `NSSplitViewController` subclass. I basically want to add an `NSSplitViewItem` programmatically and what happens is that it is added twice because `windowDidLoad()` is called twice.

In order for me to mitigate this, I would have to write code to check that the `NSSplitViewItem` I want to add, does not exist in the view hierarchy.

I tried cleaning the build folder, deleting the segue connection and rebuilding it. I am not sure what else to do. I believe `windowDidLoad()` method should only be called once.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Create a brand new Xcode project, choose `macOS` template, storyboard interface and `Swift` language.
2. Create a new storyboard file and add a Window Controller from the library and make sure it is the initial controller.
3. Create a new Cocoa class and make sure it is a subclass of `NSWindowController`. Give it a class name.
4. Assign it to the new Window Controller you made for that new storyboard file.
5. Edit the new `NSWindowController` class file by adding `print("Is this called once?")` statement at the end of `windowDidLoad()` method override.
6. In `Main.storyboard` file, on the Main Menu, File menu, add a new menu item on top of File menu item and make a segue connection to the new storyboard file you created.
7. Run the app and click on that new menu item that is supposed to open the new window controller. Look at the console log and you should see the print statement is called twice.

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that when it is storyboard-based? I don't think I am supposed to post the XML code. I can tell you that one of the segues is triggered by clicking on the `NSToolbarItem`. If that is helpful.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project?

Comment: I have made one and the issue is reproduced. What's the best way to share this on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Post the steps. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622159/context-menu-ibactions-not-firing-in-xcode-7-beta)

Comment: I've added the reproduction steps.

Comment: How do I make a segue to a storyboard file?

Comment: Add a Storyboard Reference object from the Library and make a segue connection to it. Make sure it references to the specific storyboard file.

Comment: It looks like a bug in AppKit to me. Better let the view controller modify the view in `viewDidLoad`.